# Renaming files with two different extension

Tags: python

I'd like to rename files in the current directory with the *.inp and *out extensions

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob
import os

for namefile in glob.glob('*.inp'):
        new_namefile = namefile.replace('dim', 'mon')

        os.rename(namefile, new_namefile)
```

How can I rename files *.inp and *.out at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from glob import glob
...
for namefile in glob('*.inp')+glob('*.out'):
```